# --install-space on hydro fails

Tags: ros, installation, ros-hydro, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Installing hydro on osx 10.8.5 isolated just went fine, however when it want to install it to the usual place /opt/ros/hydro

with  ./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated --install --install-space /opt/ros/hydro the following error happens:

```
Unhandled exception of type 'RuntimeError':
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./src/catkin/bin/../python/catkin/builder.py", line 785, in build_workspace_isolated
    number=index + 1, of=len(ordered_packages)
  File "./src/catkin/bin/../python/catkin/builder.py", line 559, in build_package
    "'\n  This sometimes occurs when a non-catkin package is "
RuntimeError: No env.sh file generated at: '/opt/ros/hydro/env.sh'
  This sometimes occurs when a non-catkin package is interpreted as a catkin package.
  This can also occur when the cmake cache is stale, try --force-cmake.
<== Failed to process package 'catkin': 
  No env.sh file generated at: '/opt/ros/hydro/env.sh'
  This sometimes occurs when a non-catkin package is interpreted as a catkin package.
  This can also occur when the cmake cache is stale, try --force-cmake.
Command failed, exiting.
```

Any ideas how to solve this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/89036/--install-space-on-hydro-fails/) by [J.M.T.](https://answers.ros.org/users/3816/j.m.t./) on ROS Answers with karma: 266 on 2013-10-09

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
<== Failed to process package 'catkin': 
  No env.sh file generated at: '/opt/ros/hydro/env.sh'
  This sometimes occurs when a non-catkin package is interpreted as a catkin package.
  This can also occur when the cmake cache is stale, try --force-cmake.
```

I would try with `--force-cmake` :)

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2013-10-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1